# How to set up an application to use DataContracts?

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm developing a desktop application with .NET. I'd like to save some data into a file in a way that would later give me some degree of freedom in changing the data I'm saving, such as adding new fields, while retaining the possibility to read saves from older formats.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3185392/399317) recommends to use `DataContractSerializer` instead of `BinaryFormatter`.

However I can't use the `[DataContract]` attribute on my classes in the project. After `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` I still get errors about unknown types.

The project targets .NET Framework 4.

I've learned that Data Contracts are part of the WCF framework, I assume I should somehow configure my project to use it. How?

Comment: "I still get errors about unknown types." - don't give up; research the error messages and/or post them here!

Comment: Have you added a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.dll?

Comment: @Joulukuusi Looks like that helped, thanks! I'll confirm if it works soon but the IDE finds the types. I'm surprised because [Serializable] worked without adding that reference despite being in the same namespace.

Comment: @Kos, you're welcome! In C# namespaces can be shared across multiple assemblies. Talking about this case, [`[DataContract]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) and [`[Serializable]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) are located in two different libraries.

Comment: Please post an answer so I that can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# namespaces can be shared across multiple assemblies. You have to add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.dll, which contains [`[DataContract]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) attribute.

Answer (score 1):

probably you are missing to specify the Know Type attribute when it is needed

Have a look at the below example:

```
public interface ICustomerInfo
{
    string ReturnCustomerName();
}

[DataContract(Name = "Customer")]
public class CustomerTypeA : ICustomerInfo
{
    public string ReturnCustomerName()
    {
        return "no name";
    }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Customer")]
public class CustomerTypeB : ICustomerInfo
{
    public string ReturnCustomerName()
    {
        return "no name";
    }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(CustomerTypeB))]
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    [DataMember]
    ICustomerInfo buyer;

    [DataMember]
    int amount;
}
```

you have to specify the type of `ICustomerInfo`  otherwise the serialization engine cannot guess the type

Answer (score 1):

Just add wcf service template to your application and declare your function and data members their and reference wcf in your project.